# What is the probability to pick a collection of 12 balls as above with at least 2 red balls and exactly one blue ball?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the probability to pick a collection of 12 balls as above with at least 2 red balls and exactly one blue ball? Here is my solution

${{12+3-1}\choose{12-2-1-1}}$ Is this correct?

Comment: "As above" is unclear to someone who does not remember your earlier question.

Comment: If you are the Johvan who posted [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741768/how-many-ways-are-there-to-pick-12-balls-from-large-piles-of-identical-red-wh), you should [merge](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use "stars and bars" for probability calculations.  (And that's not anywhere near how you would in any case).

The technique counts the number of distinct outcomes; however, those are not each equally probable.

To count equally-probable microstates, you must consider ways to assign one of three colours to each of 12 *distinguishable* balls.

There are $3^{12}$ ways to assign colours to the 12 balls in total.

There are $\binom{12}{r}\binom{12-r}{b}$ ways to select $r$ of 12 balls to be red, $b$ of the remaining balls to be blue, and all of the rest to be white.

So $\mathsf P(R=r, B=b) = \dfrac{\binom{12}{r}\binom{12-r}{b}}{3^{12}}$

Use this to find $\mathsf P(R\geq 2, B=1)$

---

Hint: Use the law of complements.

Comment: Fully agree. However, I would be shocked but not surprised if the expectation is that one divides the $10$ "Stars and Bars" possibilities here by the number of Stars and Bars possibilities of the earlier question.